# Change the value of a select box (html) from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, select

I have a select box in my webpage to fill a formulary. I want to recover the info filled by the user other times in it exists.

All my fields are properly filled except select box.

This is my code in html related to selectbox:

```
<br>Gender: <select id="gender">
                 <option value="man">Man</option>
                 <option value="woman">Woman</option><br>
```

It is a simple webpage just with a formulary in it. There is not anything else. I am just trying it.

With this line:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", '#settings', function() {
    document.forms[0].gender.value = userGender;
    ...
```

I am modifiying the value of that box for reading it in other parts of my webpage or send it to the database. And the value keept is the correct one, but, the displayed value is not propertly shown.

Do you know which property do I have to modify to change the displayed value?

Comment: What's `userGender`? Also, your html is invalid, either your `select` element is unclosed, or you have a `br` tag inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, then you can change or select the value of select box through jQuery!

It is very easy. Use selector and val.

```
$('#gender').val(userGender);
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not working. I am using jquery mobile. I forgot to add. I tried with val, value, selectedItem, select... And all I have got is just changing the value but not the displayed one. Also if I open the select bot to select one, the selected (marked in blue) is the correct. But I have to select it again to change the displayed.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question the asnwer developerCK has provided is correct.
Anyway look this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MWgwD/) and give a feed back if any thing we missed.

```
 $('#gender').val('woman');
```